# url doesn't match with url file

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to deploy an app, but I'm getting Page not found (404) error for my login template/view. But the same code works on localhost.

This is the error message:

```
The current URL, accounts/profile/profile.html, didn't match any of these.
```

URLs file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'survey.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^survey/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'survey.views.SurveyDetail', name='survey_detail'),
    url(r'^confirm/(?P<uuid>\w+)/$', 'survey.views.Confirm', name='confirmation'),
    url(r'^privacy/$', 'survey.views.privacy', name='privacy_statement'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^piechart/$', 'survey.views.piechart', name = 'chart_code.html'),
    url('^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
    url('^accounts/login/$', 'survey.views.login'),
    url('^accounts/auth/$', 'survey.views.auth_view'),
    **url('^accounts/profile/$', 'survey.views.profile'),**
    url('^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
    url(r'^map/$','survey.views.javamap', name = 'chart_code.html'),
    url(r'^charts', 'survey.views.charts', name='charts'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^accounts/auth/profile', 'survey.views.profile', name = 'profile.html'),
    url(r'^profile', 'survey.views.profile', name = 'profile.html'),
    url(r'^accounts/auth/results', 'survey.views.survey_name', name = 'results.html'),
    url(r'^answer_survey', 'survey.views.answer_survey'),
    url(r'^results/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'survey.views.SurveyResults', name='results'),


)
```

The profile views:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated():
        n_survey = Survey.objects.filter(user = user)
        if n_survey:
            print "*---------- str " + str(n_survey)
            for survey in n_survey:
                print "survey id " + str(survey.id)
            n = len(n_survey)
            print "n " + str(n)
            return render(request, 'profile.html')
        else:
            print("*---------- sem surveys para print")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('profile.html')
    else:
        msg = "Usuario ou senha digitados incorretamente"
        return HttpResponseRedirect('home.html', {'msg': msg})
```

In localhost, the URL accounts/profile matches because django doesn't incluse profile.html at the end. How to solve this?

Comment: I'd recommend that you don't put ".html" in the name parameter of your urls, it makes the code confusing to read since it makes it look like a relative url instead of a name.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a redirect to a relative URL:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('profile.html')
```

That means, if you are currently at `/accounts/profile/`, you will be redirected to `/accounts/profile/profile.html`. If you want to redirect to the view *named* `profile.html`, you can, for example, use the `redirect` shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
# ...
return redirect("profile.html")
```

Which is roughly equivalent to `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("profile.html"))`.

There is another problem in your url configuration: it contains some lines like this:

```
url(r'^charts', 'survey.views.charts', name='charts'),
```

There are two problems with this line

1. There is no slash at the end of the URL. It is better to be consistent and have a slash at the end of all URLs
2. There is no end-of-line special character `$` at the end of the pattern. This means that many different URLs will match the pattern, for example `/charts`, `/charts/foo`, `/chartsarecool` and so on..

Better write

```
url(r'^charts/$', 'survey.views.charts', name='charts')
             ^^
```

Comment: profile.html is a template. Why django add the string profile.html in the url?

Comment: Because you told it to: `HttpResponseRedirect('profile.html')`. `HttpResponseRedirect` _always_ [takes a URL or path as its first argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

Comment: `profile.html` is not only a template, you also use it as a name for your url pattern: `url(r'^accounts/auth/profile', 'survey.views.profile', name = 'profile.html'),`